# Looking for a DataContext extension library

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

I remember a few months ago finding a very short (three methods, IIRC) but very useful library extending datacontext in Linq to SQL.

I've been googling for it the last few days, and i'm getting more and more frustrated that I can't find it.

I know i'm not very precise/clear, but the more I search for it without results, the more I want it :)

[EDIT] It was an library, with three methods, and IIRC, one for executing stored procedures. Hosted on a big site like codeplex or googlecode (already tried to search on them). I remember seeing at least one blog post extending this library.

Comment: Here's a blog post with some extensions to [DataContext](http://richallen.blogspot.com/2008/01/linq-data-context-extension-methods.html) but your question is very vague. What exactly are you expecting the extension methods to do or what do you remember the functionality of those methods were?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm sorry about how few things I remember, and how obsessive I must sound :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found my answer : Dapper !
( http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/ )

It`s extending IDbConnection rather than DataContext, but I'm nearly sure it's the one I was looking for.